# Redimensionar JPanel

Tags: java, java-swing

Holaaa. tengo un problema al querer redimensionar un JPanel dentro de un JPanel que tiene un layout del tipo BoxLayout. Cuando agrego al JPanel de la clase principal un JPanel que contiene un JTextPane, el JPanel que agregue, ocupa un espacio grande. Mi pregunta es como tendria que hacer para que el JPanel que contiene el JTextPane, tenga el tamaño del JTextPane.

En la siguiente imagen muestro la ventana.

```
https://s23.postimg.org/vrj4nzyy3/Sin_t_tulo.png
```

Lo que esta en rojo, seria el JPanel principal.
Lo que esta en azul seria el JPanel que le añado y que contiene el JTextPane.
Lo que esta en amarillo es el JTextPane.

El JPanel marcado en azul, tendria que ser del tamaño del JTextPane que contiene. Como la siguiente imagen.

```
https://s23.postimg.org/53wq5lsx7/Sin_t_tulo_copia_copia.png
```

Osea que el JPanel tenga el tamaño del JTextPane, para que queden juntos. O por lo menos que el primero tenga el tamaño del JTextPane y el segundo no, pero al agregar un tercer JPanel con el JTextPane si lo tenga. O sea asi :

```
https://s23.postimg.org/jbmeu95m3/Sin_t_tulo_copia.png
```

A continuacion le dejo la clase principal con el JPanel, que seria lo marcado en rojo.
        public FrameTest() {
            initialize(); 
        }

```
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBounds(10, 11, 414, 240);
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);      

        PanelText p1 = new PanelText ("aaaaa");
        p1.setSize((new PanelText("aaaaa")).getPreferredSize());
        panel.add(p1);
        PanelText p2 = new PanelText ("bbbbb");
        panel.add(p2);
    }
}
```

La siguiente clase es el JPanel que contiene el JTextPane, lo que esta comentado son las pruebas que hice, con el unico que me acerque a lo que quiero hacer es con setMaximumSize(content.getPreferredSize()); pero el problema es que lo pone al medio y recortado:

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class PanelText extends JPanel {

    private TextPane content;

    public PanelText(String message) {
        setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setOpaque(false);
        setLayout(null);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 0, 0));



        this.content = new TextPane (message);
   //   setMaximumSize(content.getPreferredSize());
   //   setMaximumSize(content.getSize());
   //   setMaximumSize(content.getMaximumSize());
   //   setMaximumSize(content.getMinimumSize());
   //   setSize(content.getSize());
   //   setSize(content.getWidth(), content.getHeight());
   //   setPreferredSize(content.getPreferredSize());

        add(content);
    }

    public TextPane getContent() {
        return this.content;
    }
}
```

y por ultimo el JTextPane

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JTextPane; 
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class TextPane extends JTextPane {

private String message;

public TextPane (String message) {
    this.message = message;
    this.setEditable(false);
    this.setOpaque(false);
    this.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(7, 7, 7, 7));       

    this.setText(message);  
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Dimension arcs = new Dimension(15,15);
    int width = getWidth();
    int height = getHeight();
    Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D) g;
    graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    graphics.fillRoundRect(0, 0, width-1, height-1, arcs.width, arcs.height);
    graphics.setColor(getForeground());

    super.paintComponent(g);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo que entiendo quieres usar un diseño en el que tus `TextPane` queden alineados en una columna y pegado el texto a la izquierda. Si es lo que quieres puedes conseguirlo marcando la anchura máxima de tu `TextPane` como la de su contenedor:

```
p1.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(p1.getParent().getWidth(), 0));
```

Esto debes hacerlo después de añadirlo al frame quedando la parte en que agregas `p1` como sigue:

```
PanelText p1 = new PanelText ("aaaaa");
p1.setSize((new PanelText("aaaaa")).getPreferredSize());
panel.add(p1);//Después de añadirlo
p1.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(p1.getParent().getWidth(), 0));
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Funciono!!